# Read select option value, manipulate some characters, and write back into option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really appreciate your help:

I would like to read the select option value and change the € Symbol into EUR and write it back into the option value.

For me its possible to get the text for each value but I don`t know how to change individual characters.

Is it possible?

`<select id="filter_price" name="filter_price">
    <option value="http://www.1234.de">Alle Preise
    </option>
    <option value="http://www.1234.de/?price=2-5">2 € - 5 € (1)
    </option>
</select>`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show us your jQuery.  What have you tried?

Comment: Don't hesitate to show plain javascript either ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('#filter_price option').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/€/g,'EUR'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle showing what I made. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr7gw/1/)

```
$("#filter_price > option").each(function() {
    this.text = this.text.replace(/€/g, "EUR");
});
```

Edit: Format